# Index.html: загрузка странички на сервер

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, html

Как можно сделать, чтобы на сервере изначально загружалась страничка page.html, а не по стандарту index.html. Я читал что как-то через файл `.htaccess`, но не знаю, что конкретно в нем писать, подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Вопрос: а не проще переименовать page.html -> index.html?

Comment: @Jakeroid не проще конечно же по ряду причин!

Answer (score 2):

Вписать в файл `.htaccess` следующую строку

`DirectoryIndex page.html index.html`

Сам файл - в корень сайта

Answer (score 2):

По сути примерно так в том же htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex page.html index.php
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ index.php [L]
```

**UPD:**

В корне лежит файл htaccess.txt, что нужно с ним сделать? Его нужно переименовать в .htaccess! Как это сделать? Если файл лежит на сервере то в любом удобном для Вас FTP менеджере. Если локально то открываем файл, жмем Файл->Сохранить как->Тип файла указать как все файлы и ввести имя файа .htaccess->Сохранить и уже файл htaccess закинуть в корень.

Открыть файл htaccess в удобном редакторе и найти строку

```
RewriteEngine On
```

После нее внести

```
DirectoryIndex page.html index.php
```

Далее найти строку

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Заменить на следующее

```
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) page.html
```

З.Ы. если что не выходит, комментируйте!

Comment: так надо просто скопировать код и вставить файл в корневой каталог?
А результат должен появится сразу или есть какието фишки?
я впервые стаким сталкуюсь и совсем не ориентируюсь так что вопрос может быть мой не коректен

Comment: читайте UPD в моем ответе через несколько минут!

Comment: я так понял, что речь в вопросе не идет об уже существующем `.htaccess`.
поэтому недоумеваю.

Comment: @ikoolik как правило в Joomla этот файл нужно создать из готового htaccess.txt
Если ТС указал в вопросе .htaccess это не означает что он уже проделал описаное мною выше, так как указал что только читал об этом!

Comment: да я создавал заново файл .htaccess, проблема возникла иза кодировке,
теперь в кодеровке unix все работает, спасибо всем кто помагал!!!